# Return a value from a uwp usercontrol

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, uwp-c#

A `UWP UserControl` with 2 buttons

```
public sealed partial class SaveChangesUserControl : UserControl
{
    public bool CanGo { get; set; }

    public SaveChangesUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CanGo = true;
    }

    private void Stay(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CanGo = false;
    }
}
```

`SaveChangesUserControl` will be in a xaml page. I can bind the visibility to a property in the xaml page. `Leave` and `Stay` are event handlers for buttons in `SaveChangesUserControl`. How do I capture `CanGo` as the return value of `SaveChangesUserControl`?

Something like bool canGo = `SaveChangesUserControl` would be nice.

Like a `ContentDialog`, but not a `ContentDialog`

Comment: I’m a little confused about your purpose. Are methods `Leave()` and `Stay()` `Button.Click` event handler? Is the data binding source of `Visibility` property of `SaveChangesUserControl` located in the `SaveChangesUserControl` instance or the `MainPage` instance? I want to know if you want to get value of `CanGo` when leaving a `SaveChangesUserControl` instance, just like the `ShowAsync()` of ContentDialog.

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT Leave() and Stay() are Button.Click event handlers. I wish to return CanGo Something like bool canGo=new SaveChangedUserControl();

Comment: The constructor will return a SaveChangedUserControl instance instead of any other type of value. You could get the value CanGo from the instance of SaveChangedUserControl, does this meet your requirement? Is CanGo the data binding source of the Visibility property of SaveChangedUserControl class?

Comment: The visibility of SaveChangesUserControl will bind to a property on the page the usercontrol is used. The main page can check the value of CanGo, but how does the main page know a button in the usercontrol has been clicked and CanGo has been set?

Comment: Could you please tell me why you not use ContentDialog(ContentDialog.ShowAsync() method) which could perfectly meet your requirements?

Comment: @YanGu - MSFT We do use the ContentDialog but it has limitations. For example, we may wish to offer the user 3 or more radio buttons to choose from, or a dropdown list. The ContentDialog also has limited styling.

Comment: I have tried to get a return value form a UserControl instance as you said. But, within a method in MainPage, it’s hard to find a way to know a click event of a user control happens. The way we could implement is to do the navigation operation you needed in the click event handlers.

Comment: I also want to say that you could add 3 or more radio buttons or a dropdown list or other controls in a ContentDialog instance referring to the XAML code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog?view=winrt-19041#examples). If the ContentDialog class could meet your requirements of adding controls, I suggest you use ContentDialog class which you could get a return value by using ContentDialog.ShowAsync() method. If you need sample, I could provide you detailed code by using ContentDialog.

Comment: YanGu - MSFT thanks but we would still like to find a way to do this without using a ContentDialog. We have occasional issues with ContentDialogs causing apps to crash with "only one ContentDialog can be open at a time". It's a commonly raised issue on the forums and we've tried a number of the recommended solutions over the years without success. We've also been unable to replicate this crash on our own machines. So the next step is to try to move away from ContentDialogs and return a value from a UserControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [AutoResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent?view=net-5.0) class to do a thread synchronization. When signaled, reset automatically after releasing a single waiting thread.

Please check the following code:

SaveChangesUserControl.xaml.cs

```
private static AutoResetEvent Locker = new AutoResetEvent(false);

public async Task<bool> ShowAsync()
{
    Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    await Task.Run(() => {
        Locker.WaitOne();  //Wait a singal
    });
    return CanGo;
}
private void Leave(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    CanGo = true;
    Locker.Set();  //Release a singal
}

private void Stay(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    CanGo = false;
    Locker.Set();  //Release a singal
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var t = await myUserControl.ShowAsync();  //Call the method, you could get a return value after you click on user control
}
```